# Can binding out-of scope variables speed up your code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind

I've been doing a lot of work in Node JS recently, and it's emphasis asynchronous modules has me relying on applying the bind function on closures to wrap asynchronous calls within loops (to preserve the values of variables at function call).
This got me thinking. When you bind variables to a function, you add passed values to that function's local scope. So in Node (or any JS code that refers to out of scope variables often), is it advantageous to bind out of scope variables (such as modules) to functions so that when used they are part of the local scope?

Example in plain JS:

```
var a = 1,
    func1 = function(b) { console.log(a,b); },
    func2 = (function(a,b) { console.log(a,b); }).bind(null, a);

//func1(2) vs func2(2)
```

Example in Node

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    func1 = function(f) { fs.stat(f, function(err, stats){}); },
    func2 = (function(fs, f) { fs.stat(f, function(err, stats){}); }).bind(null, fs);

//func1('file.txt') vs func2('file.txt')
```

In my above examples, will func1 or func2 be noticeably faster than the other (not including outside factors such as how long it takes to get file stats)?

---

Here's a little JSFiddle I threw together that does a quick and dirty benchmark: http://jsfiddle.net/AExvz/

1. **Google Chrome 14.0.797.0 dev-m**

   - Func1: 2-4ms
   - Func2: 30-46ms
2. **Google Chrome 14.0.800.0 canary**

   - Func1: 2-7ms
   - Func2: 35-39ms
3. **Firefox 5.0**

   - Func1: 0-1ms
   - Func2: 35-42ms
4. **Opera 11.11 Build 2109**

   - Func1: 21-32ms
   - Func2: 68-73ms
5. **Safari 5.05 (7533.21.1)**

   - Func1: 23-34ms
   - Func2: 71-78ms
6. **Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421**

   - Func1: 10-17ms
   - Func2: 14-17ms
7. **Node 0.4.8 REPL**

   - Func1: 10ms
   - Func2: 156ms @ 10x more iterations (~15.6ms if both tested with 100000 iterations)

*Note:* Node's REPL test is unreliable because it must employ some sort of caching system. After a single benchmark of func1, func2 returned 0ms.

Feel free to contribute your results of a better benchmark.

Comment: Well, calling "func2()" will involve **2** function calls before you get to the "good part", instead of one.

Comment: How? Wouldn't the bind function be called to initialize the variable before the function is called?

Comment: Well, I suppose that V8 *could* implement "bind()" such that it didn't really return an ordinary function reference, but that'd be somewhat strange.

Comment: I assumed that browser functions (especially in a fast engine like V8) were written in lower levels of code to improve performance. On browsers that don't support bind, you are 100% right. The workaround requires two functions (and doesn't solve the scope problem). I'm not sure on browsers that do, though. There might be some behind the scenes magic involved!

Comment: `.bind` is always going to be slower because you have the overhead of an extra function call, which outweighs the overhead of looking up a level in scope.  `bind` ___has___ to include an extra function call, even if you don't see it, because you need an enclosing scope to reference variables.  You can see this by typing `(function(){}).bind(1, 2, 3).toString()` into a node console.  You'll see "function [native code]", which is the native bind function

Comment: Would the native code it produces be native JS or native C++/C?

Comment: [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) is a much better way to do this kind of speed testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the effect of reducing scope lookups should be positive. However, the difference is probably rather miniscule on today's fast JS engines.

In some math-intensive code running on an older JS engine, I used to get some more perf by doing things like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    var round = Math.round;
    var floor = Math.floor;

    //Do something that calls floor and round a lot
}
```

So basically bringing functions from outside the function to inside the function's own scope *can* have a positive effect, but to be sure you probably should profile the code to be sure.

Comment: I've begun a bit of basic bench-marking right now! I like your grab-out-of-scope-from-inside-of-function approach. I think I'll add it to my tests. In your experience, would you say this grab from inside technique would be better than just passing the value in?

Comment: I haven't actually tried passing the funcs as params so can't really say about that.

Comment: Nor have I. I guess its up to trial and error and some benchmarking.

Comment: FYI, that method is still significantly faster in many browsers.  See test at http://jsperf.com/outer-vs-inner-references.  In V8 (node.js / chrome), however, it's more-or-less even.  Actually ___not___ doing this is a little faster.

Comment: @cwolves Nice benchmark. I guess this is just another quirk of JS!

Comment: @cwolves: I think that benchmark might be flawed. It looks like you're testing more of the cost of hash lookups rather than cost of looking for variables in an outer scope. I think you really wanted to see the effect of bringing them into local scope you should try it with non-object variables (e.g. primitives) which are defined outside of the function.

Comment: @CD - You're right.  It's actually testing both, but I already know that scope lookup has no impact (literally, none.  <1ms over millions of iterations) in V8.

Comment: @cwolves: Here's an edit I made to your test case: http://jsperf.com/outer-vs-inner-references/2 The difference seems to be non-trivial in FF/Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

As some of the users in your comments have pointed out, the bind function adds some overhead so it's not really an accurate comparison. You should test it by calling the function with arguments rather than by wrapping it with another function to bind arguments to it.

Here's a test to demonstrate (original test by cwolves):

http://jsperf.com/outer-vs-inner-references/2

**Setup:**

```
var x = 10, y = 11, z = 12, z = 13, a = 14, g = 15;
```

**Test Case #1 (Outer reference):**

```
(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
        x + y + z + a + g
    }
})();
```

**Test Case #2 (Local reference):**

```
(function(x,y,z,a,g){
    for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
        x + y + z + a + g;
    }
})(x,y,z,a,g);
```

**Results**:

According to this test, the second test case is much faster than the first case. Honestly, I was a bit surprised and am wondering if my own test is flawed. I knew it would be faster but figured the differences would be negligible - but apparently not?

Comment: In the Node REPL - Test #1: 14285714 ops/sec Test #2: 25000000 ops/sec - My numbers may seem off, but like I said, I think there's some caching behind the scenes. Still, relatively the results demonstrate your point. Binding is certainly slow, but if you use inner references, it's faster than outer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some benchmarks I completed (see question) and Jani's advice, it seems that on today's new-age browsers scope problems have been alleviated with fast engines like V8. In theory, decreasing the number of scope look-ups should increase speed, but the tests didn't support this.
For those specifically dealing with Node.JS, it seems like the only overhead you need to worry about is the first iteration of a function. When something is called repeated times in Node it seems like the V8 engine is able to cache part of the function's execution for later use. To avoid this caching a larger number of iterations was used for func2. Simple math showed that after scaling the test for func2, it was approximately 5.6ms slower than func1. Given the fluctuation you can see in most browsers, I would guess that both probably dance around values between 5ms and 15ms. I would recommend however, sticking with the func1 method as it seemed to have a slight edge and is more widely supported (I'm looking at you IE lt 9).

Comment: FYI, scope has absolutely no impact in V8.  I've tested this on a 1,000 level deep scope and there's no difference between that and a 1-level deep scope for variable lookup.